# Sort the labels in ggplot barplot in ascending order of table values

Tags: r, ggplot2

Data :

```
df <- structure(list(Pathways = structure(c(6L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
    5L, 14L, 11L, 13L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 15L, 10L, 6L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
    2L, 5L, 14L, 11L, 13L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 15L, 10L), .Label = c("Angiogenesis (P00005)", 
    "Apoptosis signaling pathway (P00006)", "CCKR signaling map (P06959)", 
    "EGF receptor signaling pathway (P00018)", "FGF signaling pathway (P00021)", 
    "Gonadotropin-releasing hormone receptor pathway (P06664)", "Huntington disease (P00029)", 
    "p38 MAPK pathway (P05918)", "p53 pathway (P00059)", "p53 pathway feedback loops 2 (P04398)", 
    "Parkinson disease (P00049)", "PDGF signaling pathway (P00047)", 
    "Ras Pathway (P04393)", "Ubiquitin proteasome pathway (P00060)", 
    "VEGF signaling pathway (P00056)"), class = "factor"), Genecount = c(89L, 
    64L, 63L, 63L, 53L, 52L, 48L, 44L, 42L, 37L, 22L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 103L, 70L, 75L, 72L, 58L, 57L, 54L, 43L, 46L, 38L, 24L, 67L, 
    43L, 34L, 27L), fold.Enrichment = c(1.68, 1.99, 1.66, 1.76, 1.76, 
    1.87, 1.75, 3.04, 1.85, 2.27, 2.47, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.82, 2.04, 
    1.85, 1.88, 1.8, 1.91, 1.84, 2.78, 1.89, 2.18, 2.52, 1.65, 1.86, 
    2.1, 2.18), P.value = c(0.000479, 6.4e-05, 0.0172, 0.00383, 0.0147, 
    0.00411, 0.0346, 4.87e-08, 0.0282, 0.00106, 0.0235, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 2.22e-06, 8.26e-06, 0.00011, 0.000112, 0.00382, 0.000866, 
    0.00408, 1.01e-06, 0.00835, 0.00192, 0.00894, 0.0123, 0.0205, 
    0.0114, 0.0332), grp = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
    "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", 
    "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
    "T2", "T2")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

I used this code to generate the figure :

```
   ggplot(df,aes(x=grp,y=Genecount,fill=-log10(P.value))) + 
    geom_col(position="dodge",width=0.4) +
    coord_flip() + scale_fill_viridis(trans='log10',option="B")+
    facet_grid(Pathways~.)+
    theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

[image]

I want the labels to be arranged the descending order of gene count of T1 and T2 such as Gonadotropin label should come first than Angiogenesis. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must to rearrange your dataset:

```
df <- arrange(df, desc(Genecount), grp)
```

Then you most reorder factor-loels of pathways:

```
df$Pathways <- factor(df$Pathways, levels=as.character(unique(df$Pathways)))

ggplot(df,aes(x=grp,y=Genecount,fill=-log10(P.value))) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge",width=0.4) +
  coord_flip() + scale_fill_viridis(trans='log10',option="B")+
  facet_grid(Pathways~.)+
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = fct_reorder(grp, desc(Genecount)), y=Genecount,fill=-log10(P.value))) +  
   #geom_col() + etc...
```